# C++ lua table mapped to lua file

Tags: c++, lua, mapping, lua-table

How can I make a lua table in C++ map to a lua script where the script defines the table properties and methods, so the resulting lua file looks something like:

```
Script.test = 5

function Script:Update()
end
```

So this script could be read in many times but each time it should get its own unique table in C++.

The idea is that from C++ I want to call each unique `Update()` method and be able to read/set its test variable.

Let's say you are making a video game and I told you if you make scripts structured like this and attach them to models that the game will run the Update() method every frame and that the variables you define are local to that script/model.

Comment: I think you want a functionality similar to static variables?

Comment: The way I see this is more Lua defining classes and somehow C++ making instances of the Lua class defined in the lua script and calling it's methods from C++.

Comment: Can you edit in a short example to your question?

Comment: hmm, the above would be the short example of what the lua script would look like. That script defines a class member (test) and a class method (Update). I want C++ to read that file and create an instance of the Script object that is defined by that lua file from within C++ so I can call it's Update() function.

Comment: Can you also add a simple use-case that shows what this design is trying to solve?

Comment: What about constructing a `local Script = {}` in your lua file and have it `return Script` at the end? Wouldn't that accomplish what you're looking for?

Comment: The question I have is if I do that how do I get the Script table from within C++ and call it's functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is just to elaborate on my comment above. One simple idea to achieve what you're describing is to just create that local table right in the script file and return that table at the end.

```
local Script = {}

Script.test = 5
Script.foo = "bar"

function Script:Update()
end

return Script
```

This is the usual approach taken to put lua modules into its own namespace and to avoid global scope pollution.

You can grab and use the returned `Script` table off the stack with something like this:

```
// load and execute your script
luaL_dofile(L, "script.lua");

// Run Script:Update()
lua_getfield(L, -1, "Update");
lua_pushvalue(L, -2);
lua_call(L, 1, 0);
```

You can wrap the above code snippet into a function to make it easier to call as many times as desired. You can even make it more efficient by caching the compiled `script.lua` somewhere to avoid reparsing and recreating the wrapping function everytime this function is called. For example:

```
lua_getfield(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, "cached_script");
if (lua_isnil(L, -1))
{
  luaL_loadfile(L, "script.lua");
  lua_pushvalue(L, -1);
  lua_setfield(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, "cached_script");
}
lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0);
// etc.
```

Comment: The problem I see is what if this script is defined 3 times? Lua Script would overwrite each other and you'd only have 1 global Script table. I would need 3 different instances of the Script table. The person making this script shouldn't be responsible for giving it a different name because this is to be a generic script that they can attach to models.

Comment: I'm thinking maybe I need to make a copy of this table in C++ and store the copy of the table off because when I read another script it's going to have the exact same name (Script) but have different properties and logic.

Comment: @user441521 `local Script = {}` constructs a table that's only visible to that script. That means each time you run `script.lua` it returns a *new unique table* that's independent from previous runs of that script. There should not be any naming conflicts.

Comment: Note that for the caching part you'll have to give it unique names for the key to avoid replacing a previous cached run.

Comment: OK, I'll play around with this and see if it works for all my situations. Thanks